# Token not getting passed to session callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-auth with prisma adapter to manage the authentication process,
however the session callback by default return a session with only some fields so the expected action to **pass any additional info is to pass it through the token callback to the session** callback then return the required session with additional info
**My Problem** is that I'm unable to access the token object in the session callback to add the extra info to the session and the token is always '**undefined**' in the session callback
here is my next-auth config

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter"
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import prisma from "@/utils/prisma"

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null
        }
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        })
        if (!user) {
          return null
        }
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password)
        if (!passwordMatch) {
          return null
        }
        const payload = { user }
        const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET, { expiresIn: '5h' });
        console.log(payload);


        return { ...user, accessToken: token }
      }
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 12 * 60 * 60 // 12 hours
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      console.log('1');
      if (user) {
        console.log('2:', user);
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken: user.accessToken
        }
      }
    },
    session: async ({ session, user, token }) => {

      console.log('session last', session);
      console.log('user last', user);
      console.log('token last', token);
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          accessToken: token.accessToken
        }
      }
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Comment: what do u get here: `console.log('token last', token);`

Comment: I know it's uncommon  but I'm getting Undefined

Comment: in jwt return the object in `Promise.resolve({})`

Comment: tried that 
 jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      console.log('1');
      if (user) {
        console.log('2:', user);
        return Promise.resolve({
          ...token,
          accessToken: user.accessToken
        })
      }
    },
and didn't work (still undefined) :(